# JavaScript: how to handle all consequent pairs of elements?

Tags: javascript, lambda, functional-programming, reduce

I have an array of words:

```
["get", "out", "of", "the", "way"]
```

and a function:

```
isPrepOrParticle
```

that returns *true* for elements *"out"* and *"of"*.

I would like to glue all *true* elements to previous ones with underscore and get the following:

```
["get_out_of", "the", "way"]
```

Is there **a nice functional way** to do so by applying some kind of function to all consequent tuples:

```
f = (a, b) => {
  if (isPrepOrParticle(b)) return a + "_" + b;

  return null;
}
```

Comment: How are you calling function `f`

Comment: @brk That states the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need to manipulate the array and individual elements, I think Array.reduce is your best bet.

```js
var words = ["get", "out", "of", "the", "way"];
var special = ["out", "of"];

var janked = words.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (special.includes(el) && acc.length) {
    // append underscore + current element to previous element
    acc[acc.length - 1] += "_" + el;
  } else {
    // just add this element to the array
    acc.push(el);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(janked);
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe `reduceRight` also provides a nice way to do this in a purely functional way:

```js
const merge = (words, preps) =>
    words.reduceRight(([b, ...rest], a, i) => 
        preps.has(words[i+1]) ? [a+"_"+b, ...rest] : b ? [a, b, ...rest] : [a], []);

console.log(merge(["get", "out", "of", "the", "way"], new Set(["out", "of"])));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a classic recursive solution, it might look like this:

```js
const isPrepOrParticiple = word => word === 'out' || word === 'of';

function glue(a, b, ...rest) {
  if (a) {
    if (b) {
      if (isPrepOrParticiple(b)) {
        return glue(`${a}_${b}`, ...rest);
      }
      return [a, ...glue(b, ...rest)];
    }
    return [a];
  }
  return [];
}

const input = ['get', 'out', 'of', 'the', 'way'];

console.log(glue(...input));
```

Comment: I'm always a fan of the recursive definitions :D The `if (a)` and `if (b)` makes me uncomfortable though because relying on JavaScript's truthiness often creates a great hiding place for hard-to-find bugs. In most cases, I think use of default arguments will result in a more robust program, and one which is more transparent about its behavior. Thanks for sharing ++

Answer (score 1):

Here's another classic recursive definition to compliment Jordan's program. It's written using expressions instead of statements -

```js
const glue = (a = "", b = "", ...rest) =>
  b === ""                      // base: no b
    ? [ a ]
: a === ""                      // inductive: some b, no a
    ? []
: isPrepOrParticiple (b)        // inductive: some b, some a, participle
    ? glue (`${a}_${b}`, ...rest)
: [ a, ...glue (b, ...rest) ]   // inductive: some b, some a, non-participle

const isPrepOrParticiple = word =>
  word === 'out' || word === 'of'

console .log (glue ('get', 'out', 'of', 'the', 'way'))
// [ 'get_out_of', 'the', 'way' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Here idea is

- First we initialize two property on object `final` and `temp`
- We check the next index if it is `out` or `of` we add the current value to `temp`
- once the next index is not `out` or `of` we add the `temp` and `current value` to final after joining with `_` and set temp again back to empty array

```js
let arr = ["get", "out", "of", "the", "way"]

let op = arr.reduce((op,inp,i)=>{
 if( arr[i+1] === 'out' || arr[i+1] === 'of' ){
  op.temp.push(inp)
 } else {
  op.final.push([...op.temp,inp].join('_'))
  op.temp = []
 }
 return op
},{final:[],temp:[]})

console.log(op.final)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution close to what you have in the question, then you can simply make `reduce` return a string of words delimitted by a character such as `','` (for example `"get_out_of,the,way"`) and then `split` the resulting string by that character:

```
let result = arr.reduce((a, b) =>
   isPrepOrParticle(b)? a + "_" + b: a + "," + b
).split(",");
```

Just make sure to use a character not used by any of the strings in the array `arr`.

**Note:** This solution expects `arr` to at least have one item in it. You might check that first before executing the code above.